# For loop only returning value on first item

Tags: java

I have the following code that returns a bunch of IDs as a String type. Then I separate each ID from the String and pass them to another method to convert it to a name. But only the first ID gets converted while the rest remains as is.

```
    String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
        // returns string of IDs seperated by comma
```

An example of units would be (the number of ID could be different):

```
[97ec2452-4460-4796-a3a4-38fba1ab8ffc, 56e12fc4-97b3-44e7-b59a-5df0267424ac, e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4]


    String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1);
    String [] units3 = units2.split(",");

    for (String str : units3) {
        String unitName = UnitRepository.getUnitName(str);
    }
```

So lets say I go with this:

```
            String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
            // returns string of IDs seperated by comma

            String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1);
            String [] units3 = units2.split(",");

            String[] convertedArray = new String[units3.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < units3.length; i++) {
                convertedArray[i] = UnitRepository.getUnitName(units3[i]);
            }
```

This still only converts the first ID to a unit name. Unit names might look like this:

```
[unit-one, unit-two, unit-three]
```

instead I am seeing:

```
 [unit-one, 56e12fc4-97b3-44e7-b59a-5df0267424ac, e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4]
```

How do I get every ID as a unit name?

Thanks guys. I actually figured it out before I saw these most recent post. By breaking the IDs up to see if they second or third would at least convert to name when the first ID wasn't present. That is when I noticed the simple problem of the white space causing it to not work.

```
            String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
            // returns string of IDs seperated by comma

            String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1);
            String [] units3 = units2.split(",");

            String[] convertedArray = new String[units3.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < units3.length; i++) {
                convertedArray[i] = UnitRepository.getUnitName(units3[i].trim());  // .trim() fixes this. 
            }
```

Many thanks to all.

Comment: Also, what is the value of "units" at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [trim()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm) while invoking to getUnitName():

```
convertedArray[i] = UnitRepository.getUnitName(units3[i].trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

As it sits your code will keep overwriting the last instance of unitName on each iteration of the for loop leaving only the last value visible... did you want to maybe concatenate it instead?

If **concatenation** is what you want try this:

```
String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
// returns string of IDs seperated by comma

String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1);
String [] units3 = units2.split(",");

String unitName;
for (String str : units3) {
    unitName += UnitRepository.getUnitName(str) + ",";
}
String[] ids = unitName.split(",");
```

Comment: the operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String

Comment: @Jason change `=+` to `+=` or better use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method. Also take a look at introduced in Java 8 `String.join(delimiter, elements)` or `StringJoiner` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your input string `units` has spaces after each comma which is causing the lookup to fail. If you inspect the values of `unit3` you would see:

```
unit3[0]="97ec2452-4460-4796-a3a4-38fba1ab8ffc"
unit3[1]=" 56e12fc4-97b3-44e7-b59a-5df0267424ac"
unit3[2]=" e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4"
```

Here are a couple options:

1. `String [] units3 = units2.split(", ");` but realize that this will fail on cases where there is not a space after the comma.
2. `convertedArray[i] = UnitRepository.getUnitName(units3[i].trim());` where [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) will remove any extra whitepsace around the value, which should make the unit name to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to understand why people comment regarding the scope and wrongness of your code I simply reproduced it, and it works:

```
public class Example {

    static String getUnits() {
        return 
                   "@"    //character expected to be removed in substring()
                   +"97ec2452-4460-4796-a3a4-38fba1ab8ffc"
                   +","
                   +"56e12fc4-97b3-44e7-b59a-5df0267424ac"
                   +","
                   +"e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4"
                   +"@";   //character expected to be removed in substring()                        
    }

    static String getUnitName(String id) {
        switch(id) {
            case "97ec2452-4460-4796-a3a4-38fba1ab8ffc" :return "unit-one";
            case "56e12fc4-97b3-44e7-b59a-5df0267424ac" :return "unit-two";
            default: return "unit-three";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String units = getUnits();

        String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1); // remove bad characters from getUnits string
        String [] units3 = units2.split(",");
        String [] convertedArray = new String[units3.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < units3.length; i++) {
            convertedArray[i] = getUnitName(units3[i]);
        }
        for(String name: convertedArray) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

When you run main, it produces:

```
unit-one
unit-two
unit-three
```

In my opinion you need to know what exactly you get from `getUnits()` method, and what you are left with after you do `substring()` and `split()` and also what is the behavior of the `getUnitName()` if you pass ID that doesn't exist in `UnitsRepository`.

If you are worried about spaces on either side of the strings you can remove all spaces altogether with `units.replaceAll(" ", "");` instead of calling the `substring()` , which as you saw will actually delete the last character, if you pass `units.length()-1` as a second argument. If you want to keep last character, you should simply use `units.length()` because javadoc of the method says:

```
    * @param      beginIndex   the beginning index, inclusive.
    * @param      endIndex     the ending index, **exclusive**.
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
// returns string of IDs seperated by comma

String units2 = units.substring(1, units.length()-1);
String [] units3 = units2.split(",");

String[] convertedArray = new String[units3.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < units3.length(); i++) {
    convertedArray[i] = UnitRepository.getUnitName(units3[i]);
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain what you want really want. By the way, you used my answer to made edits on your post.

Comment: @Jason see here. My answer is correct. Why downvote?

Answer (score -2):

In the for loop, you are creating a variable that will only be visible in the loop itself. To make it visible (or "in scope"), you'll need to declare it outside the loop.

```
String unitName = null;
for (String str : units3) {
   unitName = UnitRepository.getUnitName(str);
}
// You can use "unitName" outside the loop
```

Although this loop is a bit pointless as the variable will always be assigned to the last element and will replace the previous value, so you will need to refine your logic.

Comment: I think you want to use "+=" instead of "=".